# How To Scrape next element after h2

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am quite newbie for Puppeteer. But, i try to inspect my website

```
<div>
    <h2> Movie Star </h2>
     <h3> <a href=www.x.com rel=tag> actor</a> 
        , 
        <a href=www.google.com rel=tag >actor</a> 
        ,
        <a href= www.facebook.com rel=tag> actor</a> </h3>
     </div>
```

then i tried to scrape the link and the values of it with this method

```
let actorLinks = null
let actors = null

        h2Elements.forEach((h2Element) => {
          switch (h2Element.textContent) {
    case 'Movie Star':
                  const actorsElements = Array.from(h2Element.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('a[rel="tag"]'));
                  actorLinks = actorsElements.map(actorsElement => actorsElement.href);
                  actors = actorsElements.map(actorsElement => actorsElement.textContent);
                  break;}};
```

and its worked out but the problem is when i see the same type with different structure like this.

```
 <div>
        <h2> Movie Star </h2>
         <h3> <a href=www.x.com rel=tag> actor</a> </h3>
            , 
          <h3> <a href=www.google.com rel=tag >actor</a> </h3>
            ,
           <h3> <a href= www.facebook.com rel=tag> actor</a> </h3>
         </div>
```

its only show a data instead several data unlike when i facing the previous structure. my question is how to solve it

Comment: thanks, i realize that i could easily grab the parent. it help

Comment: Actually I don't think my above code is accurate, so I removed it, but I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both structures should be parseable the same way, by stepping up to the parent container and ignoring the `<h3>`s, except to optionally increase specificity of the `<a>`s if there are other elements in the way:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.0.2

const html = `
<div>
  <h2> Movie Star </h2>
  <h3> <a href=www.x.com rel=tag> actor</a> 
     , 
     <a href=www.google.com rel=tag >actor</a> 
     ,
     <a href= www.facebook.com rel=tag> actor</a> </h3>
  </div>
<div>
  <h2> Movie Star </h2>
   <h3> <a href=www.x.com rel=tag> actor</a> </h3>
      , 
    <h3> <a href=www.google.com rel=tag >actor</a> </h3>
      ,
     <h3> <a href= www.facebook.com rel=tag> actor</a> </h3>
</div>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const data = await page.$$eval("h2", els =>
    els
      .filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === "Movie Star")
      .map(el =>
        [
          ...el.parentElement.querySelectorAll('h3 a[rel="tag"]'),
        ].map(el => ({
          title: el.textContent.trim(),
          href: el.getAttribute("href"),
        }))
      )
  );
  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Another variant is replacing `.parentElement` with `.closest("div")`. If these elements have classes or roles, it's better to use those than tags, though.

Depending on your structure, if those enclosing `<div>`s have a distinct class, which they usually do, I'd prefer a top-down approach, like:

```js
const data = await page.$$eval("div" /* preferably a class */, els =>
  els
    .filter(
      el =>
        el.querySelector(":scope > h2").textContent.trim() ===
        "Movie Star"
    )
    .map(el =>
      [...el.querySelectorAll('h3 a[rel="tag"]')].map(el => ({
        title: el.textContent.trim(),
        href: el.getAttribute("href"),
      }))
    )
);
```

As always, if the elements are added after the page is loaded, be sure to use `page.waitForSelector('h3 a[rel="tag"]')` to block until they're available.